Why running second space makes my phone run much slower?
https://www.quora.com/Will-my-phone-get-slow-if-I-use-the-second-space-feature-of-the-MIUI-8
Many says that.
Saying that the RAM will be divided.
Here is the thing.
The apps in second space is most of the time dormant.
So why should the RAM be divided all the time?

The linked post doesnzcontain anything like a "divided RAM". It simply explains that if you create a second user account you will have a lot of system processes run twice which means they consipume CPU and RAM. The latter of course even if the app is dormant.

So CPU and RAM is consumed even when an app is dormant? This is not the case for PC. Why it's the case for android?

If a program has been started on a PC it consumes RAM and it can consume CPU, thus it is the same. It is just your understanding what a "dormant" app is in an Android phone which is wrong.
